# On Noteflight, I would like to change the staff (score) key signature. How do I do this without keeping absolute pitch? (It adds accidentals.)

Tags: key-signatures, noteflight

Here is what it looks like before:
[image: Before]

The key signature change only adds accidentals to the 'affected" notes. Thus, even a staff/score transposition does not solve my problem:
[image: After]

If the score were long, I would have to change many notes by hand. (However, I am just trying to identify the piece, as a Scarlatti Sonata number, from the piano score to Tommasini's ballet *Le Donne di buon umore*.)

Comment: Shouldn't stuff like this be asked from customer support?

Comment: About the sonatas, have a look at the French wikipedia page on the ballet: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_donne_de_buon_umore

Comment: @musicamante Yes, I have saved all the YouTube videos (and hundreds of Scarlatti), however the orchestral listing has about 7 movements while this has thirteen.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica I was looking for user-involved feedback for faster response. After cleaning it up, it appears to K. 474: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQnI0AY8IMI

Answer (score 2):

On Noteflight, **the shift key plus either up arrow or down arrow** will transpose the selected elements up or downwards respectively by a chromatic semitone. This can be used **in conjunction with the key signature change** to transpose the music to a new key with a new key signature.

The example passage is in the key of C major (or whatever key the no-sharps-or-flats signature happens to be representing here). When changing the key signature by adding 3 flats, you've changed the key signature by three semitones (coincidence) from C to Eb major. Your key signature is written in Eb, but your music is still sounding in C since the change key signature function doesn't move any of the notes in Noteflight. In order to get the correct notes in Eb, simply select the entire passage, then hold down the shift key and press the up arrow three times. You may need to use the z key as well for enharmonic respellings of notes (D#=Eb=Fbb, et cetera), especially for chromatic notes.

---

*There may also be a specific transpose feature built into Noteflight that does what the question asks, which I leave as an exercise to the reader to go research.*

Comment: > *simply select the entire passage, then hold down the shift key and press the up arrow three times.*
The problem is, the passage is preserved so only the now-accidental notes are natural, as you can see. I had to move them individually; I don't know if there is a faster way. I assume that would shift the entire passage.

Comment: @MarkC I don't quite understand what you're describing; if you changed the key signature and then shifted the whole passage upwards the correct amount, that should have taken care of it. You might need to adjust a *few* notes to their correct enharmonic spellings with the "z" key, but it should be almost perfect by that point.

Comment: You can see the exact result in Black above. I saw no option to apply the new accidentals to the existing notes oh, so it leave them exactly as written pitch wise.

Comment: @MarkC No, in black above it is very clear that **you have not used the up-arrow to move the notes yet.** I'll prove it: the first note of the treble clef highlighted in orange is an E natural (in C major, no accidental is necessary). Now in the black image, you have changed the key signature to that of Eb, which is not supposed to change any of the notes - it just *spells* the exact same music in Eb major.

Comment: @MarkC Do you see that the first note of the treble staff in black is still an E natural? It hasn't changed. If you had moved the notes correctly, your note should now be a G since we want to be in the key of Eb. So now that you have the image in black, what you need to do is **highlight the entire passage again, then hold shift and hit the up arrow three times**. If you did this correctly, your first note in the treble staff is a G without any accidentals on it and almost all of the rest of the music will be correctly written in Eb without any accidentals.

Comment: (And on the off chance that this still isn't getting you to what you want, then either your arrow keys are broken or I must ask whether you truly understand key signatures and transpositions.) @MarkC

Comment: That was outrageously off-the-mark and hasty in extreme.

Comment: Hello, @MarkC. Did you end up solving your problem? I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: There is indeed a 'Transpose' feature, in the 'Pitch' menu.  Keep the 'Change key signatures' box checked, and it will automatically move the notes AND update the key signature.